# Throttling threads in C#

Tags: c#, semaphore, throttling, api-throttling

I have a situation where I am doing WebAPI calls to a service which sometimes cannot keep up with the load. I'm keeping track of how long the WebAPI takes to respond and how many active threads I have, and when the WebAPI is taking long to respond I want to limit the number of concurrent calls to a specific number (which I'd save in a config).

What I was thinking was of using `SemaphoreSlim` but the problem would be that at that time the number of concurrent threads would most likely be greater than the number I'm limiting to. Is there a neat way of tackling this problem that wouldn't involve reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Could you include an example of how you intend to use the `SemaphoreSlim`, and explain what problem emerges by the specific usage?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm already keeping track of the number of calls I'm making, so I was thinking that I'd have `if` statements around the `SemaphoreSlim` waiting and releasing to only throttle when under load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a library that does just that. It's called `SemaphoreSlimThrottling` and is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MarkCiliaVincenti/SemaphoreSlimThrottling) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SemaphoreSlimThrottling). Suppose you had 11 concurrent threads and wanted to limit them to 10. `SemaphoreSlim` doesn't allow you to initialize with an `initialCount` of -1 (i.e. you need to release 2 before a new one can enter), but with `SemaphoreSlimThrottle` you can.

```
var mySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlimThrottle(-1, 10);
```